# java - invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java, oop

On a Java OOP project I got three errors on my constructor:

> .\Voter.java:14: error: invalid method declaration; return type
>   required
>
> .\Candidates.java:7: error: invalid method declaration; return type
>   required
>
> .\Candidates.java:14: error: invalid method declaration; return type
>   required

codes for constructor:

```
public class Voter{
    private String name;
    private int votNum;
    private int precint;

    public Voter(String name, int votNum, int precint)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.votNum = votNum;
        this.precint = precint;
    }

    public setDetails(String name, int votNum, int precint)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.votNum = votNum;
        this.precint = precint;
    }...}



public class Candidates
{
    public String candName;
    private int position;
    private int totalVotes;

    public Candidate (String candName, int position, int totalVotes)
    {
        this.candName = candName;
        this.position = position;
        this.totalVotes = totalVotes;
    }

    public setDetails (String candName, int position, int totalVotes)
    {
        this.candName = candName;
        this.position = position;
        this.totalVotes = totalVotes;
    }...}
```

i declared my constructors like this:

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Previous voter's info: ");
        Voter vot1 = new Voter("voter name", 131, 1);
        System.out.println("The Candidates: ");
        Candidates cand1 = new Candidates("candidate name", 1, 93);
    }
}
```

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 8):

In your method `setDetails` you haven't specified anything for the return type, if it is not returning anything then specify `void`

For `Voter` class

```
public void setDetails(String name, int votNum, int precint)
```

for `Candidates` class

```
public void setDetails (String candName, int position, int totalVotes)
```

One other thing, *(Thanks to  [Frank Pavageau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350869/frank-pavageau))* your class name is `Candidates` and you have defined the constructor with `Candidate` without `s`, that is why it is being considered as a normal method, and thus should have a return type. You your rename your constructor as `Candidates`, or rename your class as `Candidate` which is better.

Comment: Did that, but I get another error, 
`voteDemo.java:8: error: constructor Candidates in class Candidates cannot be ap
plied to given types;
        Candidates cand1 = new Candidates("candidate name", 1, 93);`

Comment: @Ella your constructor is called Candidate, it's missing the s to match the class name.

Comment: @Ella By the way, the class should probably be called Candidate (singular).

Comment: @Ella,  Your class name is `Candidates` and your constructor is `Candidate`,

Comment: @Ella, you are welcome, since you have joined today, you may accept any answer you think is correct, You may see [How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Voter.setDetails` function has no return type. If you don't want it to return specify the return type as `void`

```
public void setDetails(String name, int votNum, int precint)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.votNum = votNum;
    this.precint = precint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a return type to all of your methods in your voter class.

Currently here in your code you have shown just one method `showDetails()` which has no return type. Certainly there will be other methods also for which you haven't declared a return type.

Answer (score 0):

`invalid method declaration; return type required`

Error message says it clearly; you need to give return type of each method. If there is no return type just give void.

Answer (score 0):

Method should have return type which says about the type of return value(if anything is returned from the method).

If nothing is returned, specify void.

This is exactly what is missing in your **setDetails** method.