# Letter printing program have missing return

Tags: java

I am getting the error letterPrinter.java:10: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
public Letter(String from, String to) and can not figured it out why

```
public class Letter {

    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String contents;
    
    public Letter() {  //constructor calling for just the from and to;
        this.from = from;
        this.to=to;
        this.contents="";
        

    }


    public void addLine(String line) //This method adds a new line plus the string that is sent in
    {
        this.contents=this.contents+"\n"+line;
    }

    public String getText() //This method prints our information in a pre-defined format
    {
        return "Dear "+to+":\n"+contents+"\n\nSincerely,\n\n"+from;
    }



}
```

```
public class LetterPrinter{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Letter l = new Letter("Mary", "John"); //Creating an object of our Letter class.
        l.addLine("I am sorry we must part."); //Calling the method within class to add line
        l.addLine("I wish you all the best.");
        System.out.println(l.getText()); //Printing all the information we have so far.
     }
    }


}
```

Comment: Well, your class is called `Letter`, while your filename is `letterPrinter.java`. For public classes, it is required that the filename is the class name immediately followed by `.java`.

Comment: Please use "edit" to fix the formatting of your code. The error message says the error is on line 10 of letterPrinter.java. Which line is that in the code you posted?

Comment: @MarcoChaparroZambrano You should tell us the filenames in which this code is found.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `2 parameters` in the constructor,

```
Letter l = new Letter("Mary", "John");
```

But, there is no `constructor` to takes `2 parameters`. To takes `2 parameters` add,

```
public Letter(String from, String to) {  
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
    this.contents = "";
}
```

Comment: This answer indeed reveals a mistake made by the OP, however, this does not solve the the specific error the OP encounters.

Comment: @MCEmperor  I think OP has posted different error for this code. This runtime error shows when it don't find the return type of a function. Kindly read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698239/java-invalid-method-declaration-return-type-required).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your class is called `Letter`, while your filename is `letterPrinter.java`. For public classes, it is required that the filename is the class name immediately followed by `.java`.

The curious phrasing of this error message is as follows: the constructor is expected to be `letterPrinter`, and all other identifiers with parentheses behind them are interpreted as normal methods – which are in turn expected to have a return type.

In order to fix this, change your filename to `Letter.java`.

Comment: I think `Letter` is a sub class and `LetterPrinter` is the tester class which containing the `main` method!

Comment: Do you mean an inner class (nested class)? No, that would not cause such error message to be shown. If it were, then the declaration would be valid.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! I didn't mean any nested class. I tried to say that "I think `Letter` is another class in the same package and `LetterPrinter` is the main class." However, if I'm wrong I would be happy to know my mistake. Thank you.